# Fetch api for post not working

Tags: json, reactjs, fetch-api

I am trying to run post api in reactjs using Fetch-api.

I try to run same API on postman and it's run.

I don't know what I am missing.

code which I am using.

```
fetch('url', { 
            method: 'POST',
            mode: "no-cors", // or without this line
            redirect: 'follow',        
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
              },
            body: {
                "username": this.state.user_name,
                "password": this.state.password
            }
        })
```

In above code I am getting **500 Internal server error**

And in body if I use Json.stringyfy than goes wrong **content-type**. I need to send content-type as **json-application**

And If there is any alternative way to send POST request than also tell me.

Thanks..:)

Comment: Do you have a real 'url' in the fetch call?

Comment: Actually it's configure on local network..but it's work on postman..

Comment: What are the values for `this.state.user_name` and `this.state.password`? try `body: JSON.stringify({ username: this.state.user_name, password: this.state.password })`

Comment: @bennygenel yes I used this JSON.stringify({ username: this.state.user_name, password: this.state.password }) .but at that time content-type change to text. but actually I need application-json.

Comment: What do you mean by _change to text_? You can still set the Content-Type by header property.

Comment: @bennygenel I already try by setting content type through header but it is ignore that..

Comment: I found [this issue](https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/318#issuecomment-249573195) which is saying its related to `mode: 'no-cors'`. no-cors mode is setting the `content-type` header. Please try without `no-cors`

Comment: @bennygenel Now it's give "Invalid CORS request" this error

Comment: You need to setup your CORS headers or set your API. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) you can learn more about CORS.

Comment: You should basically never be able to cause a 500 internal server error to occur no matter what you do from your client/frontend code. So if the server you’re sending the request to is responding with a 500, then that’s pretty much an indication that something’s broken on the server side and you’re not going to be able to get things working as expected until whoever maintains the server fixes the cause of that internal server failure. Anyway, it’s pretty impossible for anybody here to help you without knowing what server you’re making the request to

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [Axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios)?

Example:

```
axios.post('url', {
    username: 'Fred',
    password: 'xyz'
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: I install axios using npm.but I am getting axios is undefined error. Is it need to import from any where.

Comment: You need to import it in the component where you use it.

Comment: Now, I am getting error "Invalid CORS request" like this..
So it's CORS error.

Comment: Do you have access to the server? You need to allow CORS requests.

Comment: Yes,Actually It's working in postman so, It should be worked over here...

Comment: Postman doesn't care about SOP, it's a dev tool not a browser. CORS issue is only on browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have passed the body directly without using JSON.stringify. Try to use this code.

```
const sendData = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify({
      name: 'name2',
      nature: 'nature'
    })
  }
  fetch('http://localhost:3003/newRegistration/',sendData)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log('data',data))
```